# Match node except for grandchild node

Tags: xslt, xpath, html-lists

## Background

Converting a document from OpenOffice to DocBook format.

## Problem

Parts of the document include the following:

```
<ul><li><ul><li><ul><li><p>...</p></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

While other parts of the document include:

```
<ul><li><p>...</p></li></ul>
```

I tried to match just the inner-most `ul` tag using:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:ul[not(child::xhtml:li/child::xhtml:ul)]">
...
</xsl:template>
```

But this does not match. The following expression:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:ul">
```

Will create, as expected:

```
<itemizedlist>
<itemizedlist>
<itemizedlist>
...
</itemizedlist>
</itemizedlist>
</itemizedlist>
```

#### Desired Output

The desired output format, regardless of `ul` nesting, is:

```
<itemizedlist>
...
</itemizedlist>
```

## Question

What's the correct syntax for matching the innermost child `ul` node?

## Ideas

There are a few ways to resolve this:

- Search/replace the original document (there are only ~20 instances).
- Use `xsl:test` within the `li` node to see if the child node is `ul`.

What XPath expression would work? For example:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:ul[not(grandchild::xhtml:ul)]">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:ul[not(descendant::xhtml:ul)]">
  <itemizedlist><xsl:apply-templates /></itemizedlist>
</xsl:template>
```